# Align divs vertically using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align three `div` blocks vertically using flexbox.

I can get them horizontally aligned correctly, however not vertically.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.banner {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #01b9d5;
  color: white;
  height: 55px;
}
.banner-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.banner-hero {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner-left {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner-right {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="container banner-align">
    <div class="banner-left">
      Left Block
    </div>
    <div class="banner-hero">
      <b>Title</b>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-right">
      Right block
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqc1qfk1/1/

Comment: It's because the container with the `.banner-align` style is only as height as his items and so sticks to the top. Make it for example `height: 100%` and his items will align to their align-self property.

Comment: You mean like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqc1qfk1/4/)

Comment: @Hunter Turner, michaPau yeah, it's a easy as that. Very simple mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply enable `wrap` on the container and give each flex item a `width: 100%`:

```
.banner-align {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.banner-align > * {
   flex: 0 0 100%;
 }
```

Now each flex item consumes all the space in the row, forcing other elements to create new rows.

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqc1qfk1/7/)

Answer (score 11):

**You are missing the `flex-direction:column` attribute of flex.**

By default any flex container has a `flex-direction: row` & that is the reason its moving horizontally & not vertically. You need to specify this explicitly.

[Here is more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

```
.banner-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border:1px solid green;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Updated the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqc1qfk1/5/).

Comment: I think he's trying to make a row with the items all vertically centered, not make a column

Answer (score 1):

`align-items: center` on your flex parent centers everything vertically. However, using `align-self: [anything but center]` on the children overrides this.

Edit:

oops, as someone else pointed out, you're not getting the `align-self` effect in the original fiddle because the parent's height wasn't set and so it was only as tall as it needed to be to contain the children. If the children hadn't all been the same height, you would've seen them staggered.

If you're trying to have them all centered, you can get rid of the `align-self` properties and let the one `align-items: center` on the parent do that work. If you wanted them staggered, you don't need the one `align-items: center` on the parent.